# Polynomial representation of $GL(V)$: definition and examples.

Tags: representation-theory

I was reading Etingof's section on polynomial representation of $GL(V)$ and I immediately got stucked in the definition.

> We say that a finite dimensional representation $ Y $ of $ GL(V) $ is polynomial (
> or rational, or algebraic) if its matrix elements are polynomial functions of the
> entries of $g,g^{-1}, \ g \in GL(V) \ \ $(i.e., belong to $k[g_{ij}][1/det g])$

What I understood is ( let's say for example that $ V=k^n $ and so $ GL(V) = GL_n(k):=G$ with $k$ algebraically close field):

If $Y$ is a representation of $G$, $G$ acts linearly on $Y$, so every element $g \in G$ defines an endomorfism of $Y$, thus to every element $ g \in G$ is associated a matrix $ M_g \in GL(Y) $. If the entries of this matrix are polynomial functions in the entries of $g,g^{-1}$ ( i.e., they lie in $k[(g)_{ij},(g^{-1})_{ij}: 0 \leq i,j \leq n]$, we say that $ Y $ is polynomial.

Is this correct?
Furthermore, does the definition of polynomial representation for $GL_n(k)$ easily extend to polynomial representation of   $ \  \prod_{i=1}^m GL_{n_i}(k)$ ? How?

Just to be clear, I'm studying quiver representation, and I need this notions to solve Problem 5.2 in Etingof's notes, that seems impossible to me right now.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: You are correct. However, we can (as quoted) get along with the $g_{ij}$ and $\frac1{\det g}$ alone as the $(g^{-1})_{ij}$ are themselves polynomials in the $g_{ij}$ and $\frac1{\det g}$. -- Actually, I prefer to define $GL$ as an algebraic group by *including* $\frac1{\det g}$ as $(n^2+1)$st variable because that matches better with all variables of the product / of the inverse being polynomial expressions in the variables of the factors, i.e., without assigning a special role to the determinant (or to GL)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. However, we can (as quoted) get along with the $g_{ij}$ and $\frac1{\det g}$ alone as the $(g^{-1})_{ij}$ are themselves polynomials in the $g_{ij}$ and $\frac1{\det g}$.

Actually, I prefer to define $GL$ as an algebraic group, i.e., as a variety together with a multiplication and inverses map, by *including* $\frac1{\det g}$ as $(n^2+1)$st variable because that matches better with all variables of the product / of the inverse being polynomial expressions in the variables of the factors, i.e., without assigning a special role to the determinant (or to GL). For example, $GL_2$ is the variety defined by the single polynomial $X_{11}X_{22}Y-X_{12}X_{21}Y-1$ where $Y$ plays the role of $\frac1{\det\begin{pmatrix}X_{11}&X_{12}\\X_{21}&X_{22}\end{pmatrix}}$, and e.g. the inverses map is polynomial as follows: $(X_{11},X_{12},X_{21},X_{22},Y)\mapsto (X_{22}Y,-X_{12}Y,-X_{21}Y,X_{11}Y,X_{11}X_{22}-X_{12}X_{21})$.

With this in mind, the definition of polynomial representation of an algebraic group in terms of all associated matrices being polynomial in the group variables generalizes to *arbitrary* algebraic groups (in particular, to products of $GL$'s).